# не выводит данные из бд в представления ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста я изучаю ASP.Net MVC  и столкнулся с проблемой .Не могу вывести данные в представления. Использую SQL Server 2012.
контроллер:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MyBlogMini.Models;
namespace MyBlogMini.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    PostContext db = new PostContext();
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {


        return View(db.Posts);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
}
```

представление :

```
@model IEnumerable<MyBlogMini.Models.Post>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

### Index

```
@foreach(MyBlogMini.Models.Post b in Model)
{
    <p>@b.PostName</p>
    <p>@b.description</p>

}
```

модель и контекст:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyBlogMini.Models
{
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PostName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set;}

       }
    }


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;


namespace MyBlogMini.Models
 {
public class PostContext:DbContext
{

    public PostContext():base("PostContext")
        {}

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

      }
     }
```

Строка подключения:

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="PostContext" connectionString="Data Source=DANTE_L_LEVI-ПК\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Blogs;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

введите сюда код

Я пробовал и через Viebag выводить пусто и все и не каких ошибок и исключений не вылетает. Помогите пожалуйста с этой проблемой. Я думал что проблема со строкой подключения ...теперь уже не знаю в чем тут может быть вопросы...

Comment: а попробуйте так: `return View(db.Posts.ToList());`

Comment: а откуда в свойстве `public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }` должны взяться данные?

Comment: Ну они из базы данных должны наверно взяться ....